# How can I permit only .doc files for uploading?

Tags: php, upload, doc

Well this is my code but when I am trying to upload the doc file, the response is "Invalid file".....Thanks a lot. By the way my second question deals with rename of uploaded file to desired format "actual time + the original title" $date.

```
<?php
$datum = Date("j/m/Y/H/i/s", Time());
echo($date);

$allowedExts = array("doc");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{    
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
if (file_exists("uploaded_papers/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "uploaded_papers/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "uploaded_papers/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
  }
  }                                          
  else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: So your first IF is failing? Please specify more what is going wrong. With what file are you testing? Is this a localhost website or hosted remotely?

Comment: You can't be sure of `.doc` just from the file extension. It's only a necessary condition.

Comment: try to use javascript validation instead of php. its much more ideal.

Comment: waht if the user will disable javascript?

Comment: It works fine for jpg image/jpg but it does not work for doc  application/msword .... I am confused

Comment: Please, for god's sake, use proper indentation, please.

Comment: there is only one question..how to turn this code [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for only .doc files??

Comment: What version of Word Doc do you use? Let's start with that.. As in, what version of MS Office has created the file.

Comment: I need it just for .doc ...It means 97-2003 ... but you can create it also with 2007 or 2010 etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

To:

```
$extension = array_pop(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
```

Array_pop gives the last element from the array.

As to the proper MIME type for the Word document: http://filext.com/faq/office_mime_types.php

```
.doc
application/msword
.docx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
```

So I would go for something like this:

```
$allowedMimes = array( "application/msword" , "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" , "application/vnd.ms-word");

if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000
&& in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $allowedMimes))
```

To see the MIME type of the uploaded file, just `echo $_FILES["file"]["type"];` and see that it's not an image. Please post back the mimetype so we can see what the "normal" doc is.
Updated the allowedMimes array with your own result.

Comment: I did it but there is no change

Comment: well that is really mysterious...it works for .docx after your upgrade, but .doc still does not work... I am mad of it...

Comment: Try echo-ing the mimetype of the uploaded file ;) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hurray! The only thing I had to do was to use also "application/vnd.ms-word"

Comment: Yes great. So that's also a ms office mime-type for word.. ;) Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if this works for you

```
            <?php

        $datum = Date("j/m/Y/H/i/s", Time());
        echo($date);
        $allowedExts = array("doc","docx");
        $extension = array_pop(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword"))
        && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {    
            echo "hello";
        echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
        echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
        echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
        echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
        if (file_exists("uploaded_papers/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
          {
          echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
          }
        else
          {
            //changed file name 
            $file_name = time()."_".$_FILES['file']['name'];
          move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
          "uploads/" .$file_name);
          echo "Stored in: " . "uploaded_papers/" .$file_name;
          }
          }
          }                                          
          else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
          }
          ?>
```

Changes

1. used array_pop instead of end.
2. changed the file name to be uploaded to currenttimestamp_orignalname.doc

Comment: array_pop does not help ... when I am trying to upload the .doc file, it will warn me that it is an invalid file....

Comment: I just used the code from [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)  It work fine for images such as jpg and png as you can see...but I tried to use it for only . doc files and it does not work  :(

Comment: I have uploaded doc file .. and this code is acccepting no other file...not even image .. probably you are missing something

Answer (score -1):

why don't you do something like

```
$extension = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

if($extension[1]=='doc' || $extension[1]=='docx'){
  ///begin uploads
}else{
   ///fail message
}
```

Comment: `[1]` will access the second element in the array. Additionally `array_pop` does not return an array, so you're accessing the second char in the returned string and compare it to `'doc'` and '`docx`'. See it?